# Heroku server web socket connection refused error on client site

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, heroku, webrtc

I am new to node js development and i am using webrtc. My app is working correctly on localhost (on my pc) but on heroku server it is giving me this error:

> "WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://https//webrtc-filetransfer.herokuapp.com/' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED WrappedWebSocket
>   @ VM72:35 (anonymous) @ main1.js:20".

**server side web socket code**

```
var express = require('express');       
var bodyparser  = require('body-parser');         
var app = express();         
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);              

app.use(express.static('client'));          
app.use(bodyparser.json());    
var SERVER_PORT = 8087 ;           
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server , wss = new WebSocketServer({port :8087});      

console.log("server_started");
```

**Client Side Code is**

```
var ws = new WebSocket('wss:/https://webrtc-filetransfer.herokuapp.com/');         

       ws.onopen = function()    
       {

          // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
          var data={
            mid:"login",
            uid: myId

          };
               ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));      

            };
```

Comment: The question is possibled duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/31873181 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/35035998

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace...

```
wss://https//webrtc-filetransfer.herokuapp.com/
```

...with:

```
wss://webrtc-filetransfer.herokuapp.com/
```

Specifying `wss` automatically tells a WebSocket client library to use `https` to connect to a WebSocket server. You don't need to further specify `https` in the URI

Comment: thanks for reply  But now it is giving this error  : "WebSocket connection to 'wss://webrtc-filetransfer.herokuapp.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503"

Comment: I am Having error : Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503" again .

Comment: @GautamMishra 503 generally means service is unavailable. Check the server logs for more detail.

Comment: -server is giving this message -- "2017-02-27T14:04:55.145930+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connect
ion closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=webrtc-filetransfer.heroku
app.com request_id=c380193d-441a-4ef8-aa9f-5278733cd7b1 fwd="45.115.188.116" dyn
o=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=503 bytes=0".

Comment: I am unable to understand it . Please look at it !!

Comment: @GautamMishra https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h13-connection-closed-without-response

Comment: did you find any solution?